# {OpenCV Error} error while loading shared libraries: libgfortran.so.1: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

Tags: c++, opencv, installation, g++, opencv3.1

SYSTEM: Ubuntu 16 LTS

Compiler: g++

```
I)
```

I have built OpenCV from source. I followed these steps:

1.) Downloaded OpenCV source / code (3.1.0)

2.) Unzipped it

3.) Used cmake with default settings (cmake ..) because any other options were throwing up make errors later on

4.) make -j4

5.) successful install

Now when I compile from the command line using

```
g++ -o testwav wavfil.cpp `pkg-config opencv --cflags --libsopencv`;./testwav
```

I get the following error

```
./testwav: error while loading shared libraries: libgfortran.so.1: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

This happens for all c++ files using OpenCV only. Normal c++ files (using only standard c++ in-built libraries) work fine though.

On doing some research I cant find anything specific to this error, but I can find a solution to a general case for it, i.e., when an .so file is not found (means your libraries are missing or you dont have access permissions or need to use sudo to run the command).

I think it is because of OpenCV pointing to the wrong libraries. I had come across something about modifying .pc files but I cant seem to find it right now. I may be wrong about this.

```
II)
```

I need help setting up the OpenCV with geany, does anyone have experience with this?

Comment: Related: http://askubuntu.com/questions/48117/how-to-install-gfortran

Comment: @drescherjm Already tried that link a long time ago, libfortran is installed but for some reason OpenCV cannot find/ access it at all (Or feels it should be able to when it should be leaving it alone).

Anyways, here's the output on trying to install libgfortran3 -----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------


libgfortran3 is already the newest version (5.3.1-14ubuntu2).
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 3 not upgraded.

Comment: It's not looking for libgfortran3. Its looking for libgfortran1

Comment: If you don't want to use fortran you can probably configure cmake to build opencv without that requirement.

Comment: @drescherjm but isnt that like the pdiddy of all libraries? I think it is one of the prerequisites required to run it, no?